# How to configure JMS Listener in Java EE web application web.xml?

Tags: java, jms, listener, activemq-classic, spring-jms

We are getting rid of Spring from our web application. I need to adjust JMS Listener (consumer) that was enabled via Spring to something more basic. 
I don't see obvious way to initiate my listener via web.xml. All references I have found explain how to create listener in code. 
Is there a way to add some configuration resource definition in web.xml to invoke my Listener class on startup or I need to write code to attach my listener to queue.

Comment: It may depend on your application server, Tomcat for instance, would require to add a resource to context.xml . ActiveMQ has documentation about integration : http://activemq.apache.org/connectivity.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java EE **Web** Container does not support JMS.

You need a Java EE MDB (Message-Driven Bean - part of the EJB spec) for that.

Spring provides the convenience of the listener approach in any environment; if you don't want to use Spring and you don't have an EJB container, you need to write all your own JMS code yourself.

Comment: yes, it turned out this way. I needed to write Consumer and set listener to it within code.

Comment: Of course the real question is why you need to remove Spring if it's already performing this function for you.